# Hawt.io login page is not working

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot, hawtio

I am trying to use Hawtio + Spring Boot + external Tomcat(8.5).But during the execution login page `Log in` button is not giving any response or error in console.

**Application.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableHawtio
public class Application  extends SpringBootServletInitializer{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }


     @Override
        protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
            return application.sources(Application.class);
        }
}
```

**C:\Users\Downloads\apache-tomcat-8.5.24\conf\tomcat-users.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd"
              version="1.0">

<role rolename="manager"/>
<user username="scott" password="tiger" roles="tomcat,manager"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

**Log:**

```
2017-12-13 16:27:59.823  INFO 32964 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-12-13 16:27:59.856  INFO 32964 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 0
2017-12-13 16:28:00.150  INFO 32964 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.Application                          : Started Application in 17.99 seconds (JVM running for 33.808)
2017-12-13 16:28:00.157  INFO 32964 --- [ost-startStop-1] io.hawt.HawtioContextListener            : Initialising hawtio services
2017-12-13 16:28:00.173  INFO 32964 --- [ost-startStop-1] io.hawt.system.ConfigManager             : Configuration will be discovered via JNDI
2017-12-13 16:28:00.180  INFO 32964 --- [ost-startStop-1] io.hawt.jmx.JmxTreeWatcher               : Welcome to hawtio 1.5.6 : http://hawt.io/ : Don't cha wish your console was hawt like me? ;-)
2017-12-13 16:28:00.191  INFO 32964 --- [ost-startStop-1] io.hawt.jmx.UploadManager                : Using file upload directory: C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\\uploads
2017-12-13 16:28:00.229  INFO 32964 --- [ost-startStop-1] io.hawt.web.AuthenticationFilter         : Starting hawtio authentication filter, JAAS realm: "karaf" authorized role(s): "admin,viewer" role principal classes: ""
2017-12-13 16:28:00.307  INFO 32964 --- [           main] org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpNioProtocol     : Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
2017-12-13 16:28:00.371  INFO 32964 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina     : Server startup in 30625 ms
2017-12-13 16:28:01.690  INFO 32964 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/ExcludeTomcatBoot1]      : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2017-12-13 16:28:01.690  INFO 32964 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2017-12-13 16:28:01.786  INFO 32964 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 96 ms
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ExcludeTomcatBoot1</groupId>
    <artifactId>ExcludeTomcatBoot1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.hawt</groupId>
            <artifactId>hawtio-springboot</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.hawt</groupId>
            <artifactId>hawtio-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Error Page:**
[image]

Comment: Down voter please comment that will be the mature response for questions in SO

Comment: What does your `application.properties` look like?

Comment: Besides, please don't use `@EnableHawtio` annotation. It's no longer necessary for 1.5.6.

Comment: No application.properties is created, thanks for the reply

Comment: OK, then try adding `endpoints.jolokia.sensitive = false` to it and see what happens then.

Comment: Still same issue, I will post in Git the entire project.Thanks.

Comment: @TadayoshiSato Git project to use with this hawtio is here https://github.com/josephmicheal/JolokiaAgentApp

Comment: @sunleo did you find anything? I am facing the same error. Please update here/add an answer if you have found what was missing.

Comment: @pro_cheats no, may be you can try with latest version which could help you.

Comment: @sunleo, I am using the latest one. sprint-boot-1 worked, spring-boot-2 leads me to your case.